# Using my own photo path in $_FILE (upload in ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, upload

in a php file I created a form of upload and call another php through ajax to upload the photo. I pass the name="file" to second php, meaning that I have a string that is photo's path and name like ("C:\fakepath\xxx.JPG"), then I put this string in a variable as below:

$file="the string comming from upload form in first php";
then, `$_FILES["$file"]` or  `$_FILES[$file]` or `$_FILES['$file']`, always returning me an error like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: C:\fakepath\xxx.JPG in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\ajax_php_files\PHPfile.php on line 111
```

upload form (first PHP)

```
echo"
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1'  id='form1'>
<label for='file'>Filename:</label>
<input type='file' name='file' id='file'><br>
<input name='submit' type='button' id='submit' value='upload' onclick=\"SubmitData1('file')\" />
</form>";
```

ajax function:

```
function SubmitData1(id1){

var file=document.getElementById(id1).value;

//var file=String(file);
alert(file);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("ContextPart").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_php_files/upload_file3.php?file="+file,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

second php (upload_file3.php):

```
<?php
//$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
//$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

$file=$_GET["file"];
// here, the variable $file is a string like:C:\fakepath\fit1.JPG

//$file="C:\Picture\Amir\fit1.JPG";
echo $file;

if ((($_FILES["file (or $file or '$file' or what?!!)"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000))
//&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
```

and etc. ...

any help?

Comment: Could you please explain what `$_FILE["$file"] or $_FILE[$file] or $_FILE['$file']` is supposed to mean? Do you write the code randomly?

Comment: Can you post your PHP file with the javascript you're talking about?

Comment: in my second php, I have file as an string that shows like a path and photo name with its extension.

Comment: I know it's complicated, but I am close to do it, I just need to know, when i have the path of my photo, can I use it in $_FILES[]?

Comment: No. the name in `$_FILES` is the form name. The path could be anything. Your server has exactly zero information on paths your client produces.

Comment: but what it is returning as 'file' in second php is photo name with its path, as i mentioned above. since it's ajax and putting file is not working, i need to do something else

Comment: as i said, i tried photo name, with its path, w/o its path, w/ and w/o it's extension, none of them worked. 'file' by itself is not working too since it's ajax.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that the index of the `$_FILE` array has to do with the `name` of the file input in the form. In this case you're looking for `$_FILE['file']`.

The other issue is that you're trying to use AJAX and `GET` to upload the file. That simply doesn't work. File uploads *must* be POST, and file uploads in AJAX are not unilaterally supported. If you just use the value of the form element in GET, then it will always be something like `C:\fakepath\xxx.JPG`.

Comment: $_FILES['myphoto.jpg'], ot i tried, $_FILES['path/myphoto.jpg'] too, even w/o extension like: $_FILES['myphoto'],  none of them worked

Comment: since i am using ajax, putting 'file' by itself doesn't work.

Comment: It's not the name of the file its the name of the form element.

Comment: but what it is returning as file in second php is photo name with its path, as i mentioned above. since it's ajax and putting file is not working, i need to do something else

Comment: so nobody can help me?! I really need the solution! I shouldn't be that much hard. I am not the professionla programmer

Answer (score 0):

Found typo on `((($_FILES["fit1"]["type"] == "image/gif")` should be `$_FILES["file"]`

Comment: fit1 is my photo name, i was trying to see if it works or not. as i said, regular upload code like putting "file" doesn't work, since it's AJAX!

Comment: who is voting me down! didn't u understand the question or what? it's a new challenging question and useful for page!!